# Relation between ride frequency and wheel deflection of a car

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, dynamics

I am not able to understand the relation between ride frequency and wheel deflection of a car, as per given in Race car vehicle dynamics book by milliken. Is it something to relate with harmonic motion of a forced oscillator? I still don't get why there is a 188 in the numerator.

[image]

Comment: given no other information its a good guess its an empirical (experimental) fit.

Comment: Perhaps based on the combination of the spring rate and shock absorber damping ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a log-log plot in which $log(\omega)$ is plotted against $log(x)$.

For example, the frequency for $x=5$ is $\frac{188}{\sqrt{5}}=84.0762$ and the frequency for $x=10$ is $\frac{188}{\sqrt{10}}=59.4508$.

On the log scale, the tick marks show the original values, but the points $\{5,84.0762\}$ and $\{10,59.4508\}$ are actually plotted at $\{\log (5),\log(84.0762)\}=\{1.60944,4.43172\}$ and $\{log(10),\log(59.4508)\}=\{2.30259,4.08515\}$.

[image]